# how to add attribute to css resource to nopcommerce

Tags: html, css, nopcommerce

I have a css resource as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='~/Content/assets/global/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
```

I added this source to my `nopcommerce` plugin as a below link:

```
Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Administration/Content/calcss/fullcalendar.print.css");
```

But I can not add `media='print'` to my `nopcommerce` css resource.how can i add this attribute to my css resource in nopcommerce?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to specify that tag. NopCommerce allows for bundling and minifying the scripts you provided making one file for each position where css is included in the final HTML file, so `media='print'` would be difficult to process in this case.

As an alternative you could:

- Hardcode the css link in your main layout, but I suspect you're trying to avoid that. It provides better compatibility with IE8, if that still matters to someone.
- Use media queries for printing. That is what I would do.

  ```
  @media print { ... }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

actually i did try may solutions and after all i figured that i can add css usual resource to AdminLayout `head` and this is work for me.